# Redirecting From Aframe When GPU Not available

Tags: javascript, performance, aframe

I am working on creating a project that will be deployed across a wide number of devices. Some of these devices do not have graphics cards, they are xendesktop thin clients that are used in call centers.

What I would like to do is reroute the user to a different webpage that does not have an aframe project embedded or, preferably, use javascript to detect whether the user is using a thin client and adjust a variable based on that.

Also is it possible to detect whether hardware acceleration is enabled and redirect or adjust a variable based on that?

Comment: What browser do they use? Can you discriminate by userAgent string?

Comment: Unfortunately they use Chrome and IE so I can't just target a browser. I am able to adjust a variable based on whether they are using IE so that base is covered.

Answer (score 0):

Detect if WebGL is available:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if (gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext) {
  console.log("WebGL Yeah!");
}
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/By_example/Detect_WebGL)